# Has there been another reputation recalculation (as at 17th May 2010)?

Tags: discussion, reputation, reputation-recalc

Has there been another reputation recalculation (as at 17th May 2010)?

I ask because my SO rep has dropped by approx. 15-20 points, I believe on 17th May 2010.
It had been steady prior to this (I've not been very "active" for a few weeks) but I was receiving the odd up-vote from old answers.  Each time my rep would go up (or down!) I could see the activity that caused this.

However, on checking my rep at some point on 17th May 2010 (in the afternoon UST) my rep has dropped approx. 15-20 points (I think) with no activity recorded that would contribute to this.

Comment: How much rep you see when you browse http://stackoverflow.com/reputation ?

Comment: I'm seeing "** total rep 5690 :)" at the bottom of that page, which is exactly 6 rep points (!?!?!) more than what my SO profile shows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A drop of 15 reputation can happen because of a previously accepted answer that has been unaccepted. There is no easily traceable record of this.

Comment: +1 it's this in 99% of cases.

Comment: That's interesting.  I wasn't aware that an answer could be unaccepted after having been accepted.

Answer (score 3):

Look at https://stackoverflow.com/reputation

If the bottom number matches your current reputation(or extremely close) than it may have been recalculated. If not, then it's some other issue.

Also maybe a mod can fill in some reasons for why reputation is ever recalculated?

Comment: I think you meant http://stackoverflow.com/reputation

Comment: Bizarrely, the figure at the bottom of that page is exactly 6 points more than my "real" rep.  I'm not going to quabble over 6 points of rep, but I'm curious to know why there is a discrepancy.

Comment: @Josh that link worked in firefox somehow :P

Comment: Firefox is smart enough to append .com I suppose... or the Firefox developers use SO so they hardcoded it in :-)