# 'Real' and 'shown' reputation differ

Tags: support, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is my status bar reputation different from stackoverflow.com/reputation ?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50978/why-is-my-status-bar-reputation-different-from-stackoverflow-com-reputation)

Currently on Stack Overflow, I have `7102` reputation. If I visit

https://stackoverflow.com/reputation

to get a history of reputation, the end of that page says I have `6812` reputation.

What causes this difference? Would a global recalculation change it to the lower value? Is this dissimilarity in reputation caused by deleted posts?

Comment: related: [Self-instigated rep recalc](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14200/self-instigated-rep-recalc) and [How often is reputation recalculated?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7954/how-often-is-reputation-recalculated).

Comment: Not merely related, but the duplicate which answers your question! [Check it out ♪](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50978/why-is-my-question-in-another-castle). It basically is as Tobias explains [below](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64729/real-and-shown-reputation-differ/64734#64734 "Oh yeah, I went there"), though Jon clarifies what acts specifically affect this in the linked post.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a global rep-recalc would lower your rep, and yes, it's almost certainly caused by deleted posts. I don't know if the vote-fraud detection mechanism could cause this too or whether that would trigger an auto-recalc, though.

**edit** see also [Marc's answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7954/how-often-is-reputation-recalculated/7958#7958).

Comment: The differences arise from changes in deletion status. Not just deleted posts that affect your reputation, but the undeletion of old posts will also not reflect on your displayed reputation. As for the second part, if you are involved in a vote-fraud detection then you are subject to the same manner of recalculation.

Comment: Just for a confirmation, is it true that the so/reputation page always recalcs to show the reputation and is therefore 'real'? It should, seeing as it lists each reputation item ever. If so, why doesn't the system use that opportunity to save your recalculated reputation?

Comment: @Delan Yes, that is going to be your real reputation.

Comment: the rep shown at so/repution is "real" in the sense of being closer to what you "deserved", but the one on your profile is relevant for your abilities like voting, editing etc. So which one do you consider more real?