# Why is /reputation showing a lower value than I have in my profile?

Tags: support, reputation-audit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is my status bar reputation different from stackoverflow.com/reputation ?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50978/why-is-my-status-bar-reputation-different-from-stackoverflow-com-reputation)

I've noticed that the score displayed on the [/reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation) page is 197 lower than that in my profile (https://stackoverflow.com/users/244297/eugene-y). Is it possible to find out the reason?

Comment: @Simon Maybe. But the difference there is much lower (6) and the log is showing a greater value, than profile.

Comment: They're still for similar reasons (e.g. upvotes/downvotes on deleted posts).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your score is not updated for all changes. The `/reputation` page is the more accurate and shows what you will have after a recalc.

Possible reasons:

- You got upvotes on some answer and then the question was deleted.
- you delete a post with upvotes of your own.
- there are some more scenarios.